# Unclear sound or high pitched noise when recording with ALSA on NanoPi NEO

Tags: c, ubuntu, audio, alsa

I'm struggling with ALSA examples that can be found in [Linuxjournal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735?page=0,0)

I copied over the code into the .c files and compiled them `gcc -Wall Record_Listing4.c -lasound -o record` into executables:
Listing3 as `play` and Listing4 as `record`

I'm using [Nanopi NEO](https://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_NEO#Configure_System_with_npi-config) with [UGO soundcard](https://ugo-europe.com/product/sound-card-ugo-ukd-1086-usb-on-cable)

I made sure to point default audio device to mentioned USB soundcard.

I'm able to record sound and even listen to it using this examles, but there is an issue:
If I'm piping `./record | ./play` as is I get super loud and high pitched noise as background.

I found out that my headphones are requiring 2 chanell stereo and my mic is producing 1 chanell mono. So I tried to interleave this mono with itself to create stereo.

This brought some sucess as I managed to get rid of high pitched noise but now instead I aquired some kind of static noise on my sound.

It's my first attempt to create app using sound directly so I'm trying to understand why I'm getting the noise. `arecord` works just fine and records without issues so it's not hardware.

Below code after modifications

**Playback_Listing3**

```
/*

This example reads standard from input and writes
to the default PCM device for 5 seconds of data.

*/

/* Use the newer ALSA API */
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main() {
  long loops;
  int rc;
  int size;
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
  unsigned int val;
  int dir;
  snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
  char *buffer;

  /* Open PCM device for playback. */
  rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default",
                    SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to open pcm device: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

  /* Fill it in with default values. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

  /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

  /* Interleaved mode */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params,
                      SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

  /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params,
                              SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);

  /* Two channels (stereo) */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);

  /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
  val = 44100;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params,
                                  &val, &dir);

  /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
  frames = 32;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle,
                              params, &frames, &dir);

  /* Write the parameters to the driver */
  rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames,
                                    &dir);
  size = frames * 4; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
  buffer = (char *) malloc(size);

  /* We want to loop for 5 seconds */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params,
                                    &val, &dir);
  /* 5 seconds in microseconds divided by
   * period time */
  loops = 5000000 / val;

  while (loops > 0) {
    loops--;
    rc = read(0, buffer, size);
    if (rc == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "end of file on input\n");
      break;
    } else if (rc != size) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "short read: read %d bytes\n", rc);
    }
    rc = snd_pcm_writei(handle, buffer, frames);
    if (rc == -EPIPE) {
      /* EPIPE means underrun */
      fprintf(stderr, "underrun occurred\n");
      snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
    } else if (rc < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "error from writei: %s\n",
              snd_strerror(rc));
    }  else if (rc != (int)frames) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "short write, write %d frames\n", rc);
    }
  }

  snd_pcm_drain(handle);
  snd_pcm_close(handle);
  free(buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

**Record_Listing4**

```
/*

This example reads from the default PCM device
and writes to standard output for 5 seconds of data.

*/

/* Use the newer ALSA API */
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

void interleave(const char * in_L,     // mono input buffer (left channel)
                const char * in_R,     // mono input buffer (right channel)
                char * out,            // stereo output buffer
                const size_t num_samples)  // number of samples
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_samples; ++i)
    {
        out[i * 4] = in_L[i];
        out[i * 4 + 1] = in_L[i+1];
        out[i * 4 + 2] = 0;
        out[i * 4 + 3] = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
  long loops;
  int rc;
  int size;
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
  unsigned int val;
  int dir;
  snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
  char *buffer;
  char *stereo;

  /* Open PCM device for recording (capture). */
  rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default",
                    SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to open pcm device: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

  /* Fill it in with default values. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

  /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

  /* Interleaved mode */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params,
                      SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

  /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params,
                              SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);

  /* Two channels (stereo) */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 1);

  /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
  val = 44100;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &val, &dir);

  /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
  frames = 32;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);

  /* Write the parameters to the driver */
  rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params,
                                      &frames, &dir);
  size = frames * 2; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
  buffer = (char *) malloc(size);
  stereo = (char *) malloc(size*2);

  /* We want to loop for 5 seconds */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params,
                                         &val, &dir);
  loops = 5000000 / val;

  while (loops > 0) {
    loops--;
    rc = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);
    if (rc == -EPIPE) {
      /* EPIPE means overrun */
      fprintf(stderr, "overrun occurred\n");
      snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
    } else if (rc < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "error from read: %s\n",
              snd_strerror(rc));
    } else if (rc != (int)frames) {
      fprintf(stderr, "short read, read %d frames\n", rc);
    }
    interleave(buffer, buffer, stereo, frames);
    rc = write(1, stereo, size*2);
    if (rc != size*2)
      fprintf(stderr,
              "short write: wrote %d bytes\n", rc);
  }

  snd_pcm_drain(handle);
  snd_pcm_close(handle);
  free(buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

I've managed to solve the issue. Underlaying reason was incosistency between recording format and payback format. I needed to properly interleave mono from mic to create proper stereo without noises or static. I'm posting code below for anyone struggling.

***RECORDING***

```
/*

This example reads from the default PCM device
and writes to standard output for 5 seconds of data.

*/

/* Use the newer ALSA API */
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

void interleave(const uint16_t * in_L,     // mono input buffer (left channel)
                const uint16_t * in_R,     // mono input buffer (right channel)
                uint16_t * out,            // stereo output buffer
                const size_t num_samples)  // number of samples 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_samples; ++i)
    {
        out[i*2] = in_L[i];
        out[i*2+1] = in_R[i];
    }
}

int main() {
  long loops;
  int rc;
  int size;
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
  unsigned int val;
  int dir;
  snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
  char *buffer;
  char *stereo;
  snd_pcm_format_t format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE;
  int channels = 2;

  /* Open PCM device for recording (capture). */
  rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default",
                    SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to open pcm device: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

  /* Fill it in with default values. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

  /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

  /* Interleaved mode */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params,
                      SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

  /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, format);

  /* Two channels (stereo) */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, channels);

  /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
  val = 44100;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &val, &dir);

  /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
  frames = 128;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);

  /* Write the parameters to the driver */
  rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, &dir);
  int width = (snd_pcm_format_width(format)/8);
  fprintf(stderr,"Format width: %d\n", width);
  size = frames * width; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
  buffer = (char *) malloc(size);
  stereo = (char *) malloc(size*2);

  for(int i = 0; i < 2*size; i++){
    stereo[i] = 0x00;
  }

  /* We want to loop for 5 seconds */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &val, &dir);
  loops = 5000000 / val;

  while (loops > 0) {
    loops--;
    rc = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);
    if (rc == -EPIPE) {
      /* EPIPE means overrun */
      fprintf(stderr, "overrun occurred\n");
      snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
    } else if (rc < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "error from read: %s\n",
              snd_strerror(rc));
    } else if (rc != (int)frames) {
      fprintf(stderr, "short read, read %d frames\n", rc);
    }
    if(channels > 1){
        interleave((uint16_t*)buffer,(uint16_t*)buffer,(uint16_t*)stereo,frames);
        write(1, stereo, 2*size);
    }
    else{
        write(1, buffer, size);
    }
  }

  snd_pcm_drain(handle);
  snd_pcm_close(handle);
  free(buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

***PLAYBACK***

```
/*

This example reads standard from input and writes
to the default PCM device for 5 seconds of data.

*/

/* Use the newer ALSA API */
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main() {
  long loops;
  int rc;
  int size;
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
  unsigned int rate = 44100;
  int dir;
  snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
  char *buffer;
  char* stereo;
  snd_pcm_format_t format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE;
  int channels = 2;

  /* Open PCM device for playback. */
  rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default",
                    SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to open pcm device: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

  /* Fill it in with default values. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

  /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

  /* Interleaved mode */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params,
                      SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

  /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, format);

  /* Two channels (stereo) */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, channels);

  /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */;
  rc = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &rate, &dir);
  if(rc < 0){
    unsigned int r;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(params, &r, &dir);
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot set sample rate, using: %d\n", r);
  }

  /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
  frames = 128;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle,
                              params, &frames, &dir);

  /* Write the parameters to the driver */
  rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames,
                                    &dir);
  size = frames * (snd_pcm_format_width(format)/8) * channels; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
  buffer = (char *) malloc(size);
  stereo = malloc(2*size);
  /* We want to loop for 5 seconds */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &rate, &dir);
  /* 5 seconds in microseconds divided by
   * period time */
  loops = 5000000 / rate;

  while (loops > 0) {
    loops--;
    rc = read(0, buffer, size);
    if (rc == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "end of file on input\n");
      break;
    } else if (rc != size) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "short read: read %d bytes\n", rc);
    }
    rc = snd_pcm_writei(handle, buffer, frames);
    if (rc == -EPIPE) {
      /* EPIPE means underrun */
      fprintf(stderr, "underrun occurred\n");
      snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
    } else if (rc < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "error from writei: %s\n",
              snd_strerror(rc));
    }  else if (rc != (int)frames) {
      fprintf(stderr,
              "short write, write %d frames\n", rc);
    }
  }

  snd_pcm_drain(handle);
  snd_pcm_close(handle);
  free(buffer);

  return 0;
}
```